# Scala Play: What's the approach to externalize big JSON templates?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I'm working on a Scala 2.12.x Play 2.7.x project that calls a WS API and therefore, I have the need for storing big JSON templates with placeholders for reuse, something alla e.g.

```
{
   "birthDate": "$birthDate",
   "givenName": "$givenName",
   "familyName": "$familyName",
}
```

However, this is only for illustration, the JSONs I have are to big as to inline in the code and use String interpolation `s""`, let alone the maintainability issues of keeping this inlined in the code. Also, this above is  not valid JSON.

An idea would be to place these templates as part of some `templates.conf` but that would be abusing the `Configuration` functionality or? and besides Play would try to fill in those placeholders each time it re-loads which is not what I want.

What approach do you recommend doing for implementing this use-case?